# How to create the faded look that is achieved on this poster in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency

How can I achieve the faded transparency look that appears throughout this poster?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are referring to but try applying a clipping mask with a gradient.

Answer (score 2):

As always, there are many ways to do this effect.

First one, the easiest "cheating" way. 
Just create the object, from brush library select chalk-Charcoal (or download similar one) and paint over the object. 
[image]

Second one, easier "I Don't have time for that" way. 
Use photoshop, make gradient, use "cloud" filter or sponge eraser. After that just import it into Illustrator and trace it. Then you can skip it, rotate, skeeve and change colour. OR you can use it as mask (be careful as this is a complex object and Il may not mask properly or at all). 
[image]

And the third way, easy "I got things to do and places to be" kind of.
Just take the picture you created in previous one in photoshop. Slap it on object and use transparency. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could have been made with some cloudy texture being clipping masked with a different color toward the ends of each fade.